# flask-login current_user.is_authenticated always is False

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I've been following along and practicing how to create a flask webpage by Corey Schafer's youtube tutorials and I'm stuck trying to create the logout button, I've tried this many times and have found out that the problem lies in `current_user.is_authenticated`

Here's my **routes.py** code for the login and logout (I'm including the imports):

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from flaskblog import app, db, bcrypt
from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from flaskblog.models import User, Post
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Here's the **layout.html** code as well:

```
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                  {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
                  {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
                  {% endif %}
```

Also my **models.py** code for the User:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int())

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpeg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref ='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}','{self.image_file}')"
```

Please help me out on this, I've tried everything and nothing seems to work for some reason, I've even directly copied Corey's code

Link to the youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSHx6eCkmv0&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=6

Comment: Did you overwrite the `is_authenticated` method in your `User` class?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to pass `user_id` when a user is returned.

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

In his video, check the timestamp **23:52**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) documentation
In your User model class, you have to add some methods as properties.
As in:

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.id

@property
def is_active(self):
    return True

@property
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

@property
def is_anonymous(self):
    return False
```

**Notice that get_id method doesn't have the property decorator.**

And the load_user function isn't necessary where it is.
It should be inside the scope of the main app as that's where the user needs to be loaded. Not in the model.